# Table design with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am working on an inventory management system. In the back-end we are using POSTGRESQL database. We are having 3 tables:

```
1. invoice:
   a. invoice_no CHARACTER VARYING(20), //PK stores the invoice no.
   b. invoice_date DATE, //stores the invoice date.
   c. party INT. //FK party.id the id of the party of the invoice.

2. invoice_item:
   a. invoice_no CHARACTER VARYING(20) //FK invoice.invoice_no,
   b. invoice_serial INT, //stores the invoice item serial no.
   c. item INT, //FK item.id stores the id of the item.
   d. quantity INT, //stores the quantity of the item.
   e. discount NUMERIC, //stores the discount given on the item.
   f. tax NUMERIC, //stores the amount of tax applicable.
   g. total NUMERIC. //stores the total amount including tax and reducing discount of the item.
//columns invoice_no and invoice_serial is the PK of this table.

3. inventory:
   a. inventroy_id SERIAL //PK auto generated serial.
   b. purchase_invoice_no CHARACTER VARYING(20), //FK inventroy_item.invoice_no
   c. purchase_invoice_serial INT, //FK invoice_item.invoice_serial.
   d. sales_invoice_no CHARACTER VARYING(20), //FK inventroy_item.invoice_no
   e. sales_invoice_serial INT, //FK invoice_item.invoice_serial.
   f. quanity INT. //stores the quantity of item transacted.
//If the item is in stock then the sales_invoice_no and sales_invoice_serial is null.
```

All the invoices, sales and purchase, are stored in the invoice table.

When the sales invoice quantity is less than purchase invoice quantity, then a new entry is made in the inventory table with the sales and purchase invoice items and the sales quantity and reducing the quantity in the entry having sales invoice item as `null` by the amount sold.

The actual data is stored in  **partitioned tables** of `invoice`, `invoice_item`, and `inventory` **based on the year** so we have say for year 2015 -> `invoice_2015`, `invoice_item_2015` and `inventory_2015` with all the constraints of the parent tables. **But this creates a new problem as some items are purchased in 2014 and sold in 2015. As a result when those items invoices are being stored, there is a foreign key violation as the `inventory_2014` has the purchase invoice item but the sales invoice item is present in the table `invoice_item_2015` but the `inventory_2014` can only refer to `invoice_item_2014` table.**

Can you suggest me a way to overcome this problem or any suggestions on change in the design. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using queries or stored procedures? Try stored procedure it will work little faster!!

Comment: I am using `stored procedures`. But that is not the answer to my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "slower"? What do you mean by "increased"? What queries? Where are indexes? It's hard to talk about performance if we don't have any information.
But not using varchar for PK is usually a good idea.

Comment: "The queries", what queries? And could you please post the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE of these queries at http://explain.depesz.com ? Without this information, it's next to impossible to help you.

Comment: @JakubKania my primary problem is that after I started partitioning those tables according to year,  created a new problem as some items are purchased in 2014 and sold in 2015. As a result when those items invoices are being stored, there is a foreign key violation as the inventory_2014 has the purchase invoice item but the sales invoice item is present in the table invoice_item_2015.

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding.

Comment: @Blip "Urgent" etc... are not useful pieces of text for titles. See first answer and comments on it from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255196/remove-help-please-from-titles

Comment: @NathanKoop I accept you edit but could you suggest me a way to draw attention from genuine people

Comment: There is no magic bullet, just ask an interesting question, with all the required information up front, show that you've done your work and respond quickly (I don't see anything particularly wrong with anything you've done thus far). However, understand that sometimes your question won't be answered. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Blip I haven't used postgresql, nor table partitioning, but if they're seperate tables (per your post), then you'd need to migrate the data to them, so at the end of each year you'd "close 2014" and "open 2015", so you could create audit entries that "sell" your product to yourself on Dec 31st at 11:59pm. However, there may be much more elegant ways to handle this via postgresql.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75301/discussion-between-blip-and-nathan-koop).

Comment: How many rows per year for each of those tables? You're probably better off without partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you drop partitioning in favor of partial indexing and annual clustering.  Partitioning is an exotic solution for exotic problems and not the go-to solution for ordinary problems, at least in PostgreSQL.

If you cannot do this, then the next best would be to have a narrow join table that everything references, which is trigger-maintained.